# Couldn't match expected type ‘r’ with actual type ‘Horse’

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I'm fiddling about with Haskell but struggling with a problem. The following code:

```
class HasHorses e where yieldInHorses :: (InHorses r) => e -> r
class InHorses e

data Horse = Horse String
data Stable = Stable String

instance InHorses Horse
instance HasHorses Stable where yieldInHorses e = (Horse "Buttercup")
```

Gives me the following error:

```
source_file.hs:10:52: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘r’ with actual type ‘Horse’
      ‘r’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          yieldInHorses :: forall r. InHorses r => Stable -> r
        at source_file.hs:10:33
    • In the expression: (Horse "Buttercup")
      In an equation for ‘yieldInHorses’:
          yieldInHorses e = (Horse "Buttercup")
      In the instance declaration for ‘HasHorses Stable’
    • Relevant bindings include
        yieldInHorses :: Stable -> r
          (bound at source_file.hs:10:33)
```

Where line 10 refers to the line where I `instance HasHorses Stable where ...`.

Perhaps I've overlooked something, but I can't see why this should be an error. The actual Type Horse satisfies the constraint of r, which is that it should be InHorses.

the Idea of the 'yieldInHorses' method is that for something that HasHorses, calling this method on it should tell me the Horses (well, horse, to begin with - This wil encompass lists soon), that it has.

Have I made a simple error or misunderstood something more fundamental?

Comment: The type of `yieldInHorses` is actually `forall r. InHorses r => e -> r`, which notably means that the *caller gets to decide* what `r` should be. What you are looking for is something like `exists` instead of `forall`, which is not directly available in Haskell, though [it is possible to encode something like them using other constructs](https://wiki.haskell.org/Existential_type). However, this is such a contrived example that it is hard to give concrete advice—why would you ever need a typeclass like `InHorses`, anyway?

Comment: Instead of `InHorses r => e -> r` just use `e -> Horses` where `Horses` is a type which properly captures all of the information you want, probably `[Horse]`.

Comment: I wonder why you are using typeclasses. Do you really need them? If a typeclass will only have exactly one instance, you probably should scrap it and use the plain type directly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are looking for *associated types*.

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}

class HasHorses e where
  type R e  :: *
  yieldInHorses :: (InHorses (R e)) => e -> R e

class InHorses e

data Horse = Horse String
data Stable = Stable String

instance InHorses Horse

instance HasHorses Stable where
  type R Stable = Horse
  yieldInHorses e = (Horse "Buttercup")

test = yieldInHorses (Stable "asd")
```

Here when we define the HasHorses instance we also defined
what the associated horse type is.

As @Alexis King mentioned, your signature for `yieldInHorses` allows
the caller to determine what the return type is. For instance, they
could ask for:

```
yieldInHorses (Stable "asd") :: Int
```

But it seems you want to return a specific type based on the instance you are defining.

**Update**

Here is anther way to write the signature for `yieldInHorses` which removes
the need for FlexibleContexts and works with GHC 8:

```
  yieldInHorses :: (InHorses r, r ~ R e) => e -> r
```

Comment: I think you either need to add `{-# LANGUAGE ConstrainedClassMethods #-}` or to put `(InHorses (R e)) => HasHorses e` into a class-definition to get this compiled in GHC 8.0.1

Comment: Updated the answer with an alternative signature for yieldInHorses.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in a comment above, the type `(InHorses r) => e -> r` of `yieldInHorses` means that if given a value of type `e`, it is able to return a value of **any** type `r` that satisfies the `InHorses` constraint. The implementation, however, always returns a specific `r`, `Horse`.

It's hard to know what would work best for you since the example appears to be incomplete (the `Stable` value is ignored in the implementation of `yieldInHorses`). If a `Stable` can *only* produce `Horse`s, the functional dependency or type family approaches makes sense. If, however, a `Stable` maintains some state that can then be used to produce any `InHorses r => r`, perhaps a constructor approach could be useful. For example, if all `InHorses` are able to be constructed from a `String`:

```
class InHorses e where makeHorse :: String -> e
instance InHorses Horse where makeHorse s = Horse s

instance HasHorses Stable where yieldInHorses e = makeHorse "Buttercup"
```